# Join tables with linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 4 tables:

- Topics
- RelyTopics
- TagTopics
- TagNames.

I want to execute query with join and get 2 outputs:

- join 2 tables Topics, RelyTopics
- and join 2 tables TagTopics, TagNames

both on the same view.

In the Controller I have this code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var query1 = from to in db.Topics 
                      join rel in db.RelyTopics  on to.IdTopic equals rel.Id
                     select new TopicAndDetails
                     {
                         Topic = to,
                         RelyTopic = rel,
                     };
    var query2 = from tag in db.TagTopics
                join na in db.TagNames on tag.IdTag equals na.IdName
                select new TopicAndDetails
                {
                    TagTopic = tag,
                    NameTag = na,
                };

    var relytopics = new TopicAndDetails(query1, query2) ; //??????

    return View(relytopics.ToList());
}
```

In the Model have this code:

```
 public partial class TopicAndDetails
{
    public Topic Topic { get; set; }
    public TagName NameTag { get; set; }

    public TagTopic TagTopic { get; set; }
    public RelyTopic RelyTopic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me you may need to change your design either to hold `List<TagTopic>` and `List<RelyTopic>` inside `TopicAndDetails` OR create a new ViewModel that can hold these two lists.

Comment: Create navigation properties.

Comment: It's pretty much impossible to answer this without knowing what these entities look like. However, generally speaking, unless you can return all the information in one go, you'll need to keep them two separate lists. There's no guarantee that the number of items in query1 will match those in query2, and therefore, there's no way to logically combine them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your navigation properties first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx, then you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return db.Topics.Select(t=>new TopicAndDetails {Topic=t})
    .Concat(db.TagTopics.Select(tt=>new TopicAndDetails {TagTopic=tt));
}
public partial class TopicAndDetails
{
    public Topic Topic { get; set; }
    public TagTopic TagTopic { get; set; }
}
```

Your ViewModel would then be `IQueryable<TopicAndDetails>` or `IEnumerable<TopicAndDetails>`

Or this would make more sense probably:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return new TopicAndDetails {
    Topics = db.Topics.ToList(),
    TagTopics = db.TagTopics.ToList()
  };
}
public partial class TopicAndDetails
{
    public List<Topic> Topics { get; set; }
    public List<TagTopic> TagTopics { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: when I using  List Topic and TagTopic.
`@foreach (var item in Model.Topics) `
doesn't work . I already have used `@model IEnumerable<WebApplication3.Models.TopicAndDetails>`
How I can fix it ? tks !

Comment: Well if you are using the first method, then it would be `@foreach(var item in Model)`, if you are using the second method, then the model would just be `@model WebApplication3.Models.TopicAndDetails`.

Comment: I have run successful . Thank you for your help :))